# startx doesn't work with users

Tags: arch-linux

I just installed archlinux on an external usb drive.
I have managed to install xorg, xfce4 and gnome session.
It works perfectly when I use the OS as root user. This is because I edited `/root/.xinitrc ~` and uncomment the desktop environments .
But when I add user, I was unable to do `cp /etc/skel/.xinitrc ~` ( " file does not exist ". When I log as a non root-user and I run `startx`, the desktop environment does not work.

What have I missed?

Comment: I ended up here and realized that I `su` to the user. You should not `su` but `exit` and login properly as the user and then `startx`.

Answer (score 3):

Copy `.xinitrc` from `/root/` to `/etc/skel/` and when you add users it will be automatically in their homes.

For the existing users just copy `/root/.xinitrc` to their homes and chown it to their user:group.